# Are Grafana alerts handled if Dashboard is closed?

Tags: grafana

I am using Grafana Stack Enterprise (on-premises) to monitor my servers via Prometheus.  I created some alerts in dashboard panels.  Are these alerts processed if I close my browser that has the dashboard open?  Or do I need to leave the browser & dashboard open?

Comment: simple answer is "Yes, it will work"

Answer (score 3):

If those Dashboard/Panels are saved, everything will be processed. You don't need to have it opened.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!